# Read blocks when no data are available to read from socket

Tags: c, sockets, server

I am implementing a server/client app for educational purposes. My server opens a socket and polls it for connections. If a connection is available it accepts it and sends some data over. Then it waits for input and sends some data back again.

When implementing the client side, I tried writing to the socket right away, but that did not work. I had to receive first what the server told me and then send it some data. Then wait to receive again.

This does not seem a good solution and since this is an educational project I was wondering how I would go about making it abstract (i.e. not care about how many times the server would send me something and I would send it something back.)

So far I have tried looping to receive the server's input but without success. The server writes twice to the socket, so the client must read twice before trying to send its own message. If I read a third time the read blocks (which I think is the normal behaviour).

I tried using poll on the socket from the client's side to watch for POLLOUT events, but it does not seem to work.

```
int connect(){

    unsigned int backlog = 10;

/*
    struct sockaddr_in {
        short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET
        unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
        struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
        char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
    };

    struct in_addr {
        unsigned long s_addr;  // load with inet_aton()
    };
*/

    struct sockaddr_in server{};

    //Create socket
    listeningSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listeningSocket == -1) {
        spdlog::critical("Could not create socket");
    }

    spdlog::debug("Socket created.");

    //Prepare the socket for incoming connections
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(PortNumber); // NOLINT(hicpp-signed-bitwise)

    if (bind(listeningSocket, (const struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
        spdlog::critical("bind failed. Error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    spdlog::debug("Bind succeeded\n");

    if (!listen(listeningSocket, static_cast<int>(backlog))) {
        return listeningSocket;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Handle the message

```
void* sendMessage(){

    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = socket;
    int read_size;
    const char *message;
    char client_message[200];

    //Send some messages to the client
    message = "Greetings! I am your connection handler\n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));

    message = "Now type something and i shall apply the caesar cipher to it \n";
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));

    //Receive a message from client
    while ((read_size = recv(sock, client_message, 200, 0)) > 0) {
        //end of string marker
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';

        std::string temp(client_message);
        temp = cipher->operate(temp);

        //Send the message back to client
        write(sock, temp.c_str(), strlen(temp.c_str()));

        //clear the message buffer
        memset(client_message, 0, 200);
    }

    if (read_size == 0) {
        spdlog::debug("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else if (read_size == -1) {
        spdlog::error("recv failed: {}",errno);
    }

    return nullptr;

}
```

As for the client side:

```
//Connect to the server 

void connect()
 {
        struct hostent *he;
        struct sockaddr_in their_addr{}; /* connector's address information */

        if ((he=gethostbyname(mHost.c_str())) == nullptr) {  /* get the host info */
            spdlog::error("gethostbyname");
        }

        if ((mSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            spdlog::error("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;      /* host byte order */
        their_addr.sin_port = htons(mPort);    /* short, network byte order */ //NOLINT
        their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
        bzero(&(their_addr.sin_zero), 8);     /* zero the rest of the struct */

        if (connect(mSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
            spdlog::error("connect");
            exit(1);
        }
}

}
```

And try to send the message:

```
void sendMessage(){

#define MAX 100

    if (!sockfd) {
        sockfd = mSocket;
        spdlog::info("Setting socket to {}", sockfd);
    }

    char buff[MAX];
struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd=sockfd;



    while (( recv(sockfd, buff, 200, 0)) > 0) {

        printf("From Server : %s", buff);
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
    }

    strcpy(buff, "PAPARI");
    write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));

    read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
    printf("From Server : %s", buff);


    close(sockfd);

}
```

This will block after the two messages from the server are received by the client.

Comment: That's why usually `select()` or `poll()` loops are used to overcome blocking `read()` callse.

Comment: _The server writes twice to the socket, so the client must read twice_ - that's a very wrong assumption with SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ What would the exit condition for a poll() loop be? As far as I have seen, the events on the file descriptor do not change

Comment: You can use a separate event fd to specify the exit condiiton for `select()` or `poll()` if you want to shutdown the server.